# Mutation master-detail to lookup on delete/undelete

Tags: relationships

According to [this](https://answerstoall.com/common-questions/what-will-happen-if-we-undelete-the-deleted-junction-object/#Can_we_create_junction_object_using_lookup) materials via delete/undelete a junction object the  relationship will be changed to the lookup from the master-detail.
I am trying to reproduce this but with no success. Someone can explain the reason for this mutation and give an example?

Comment: The paragraph you linked to states that you can use Lookup fields instead of Master-Detail, but if you do so, you must write your own code to delete/undelete the junction objects when the parent records are deleted/undeleted. Salesforce will not automatically change your master-detail fields to lookup fields.

Comment: first punct on document
"When we undelete the deleted Junction Object all the Master Detail Relationship Data type will be changed to Lookup Relationship DataType."